# Where in Davening do we kiss תפילין?

Tags: tefilin, prayer-book, artscroll, kissing

It is well-known (I assume) that one should kiss his [תפילין](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin) when saying וקשרתם לאות... (twice) in שמע, when saying פותח את ידך... in אשרי, and עוטר ישראל בתפארה in [ברכת השחר](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkat_HaShachar).

Most Artscroll Siddurim also add יוצר אור ובורא חושך in ברכת קריאת שמע.

The latest edition of the Artscroll תפארת יעקב Siddur (pocket-size נוסח ספרד) also adds ישמחו השמים ותגל הארץ (twice) in [פסוקי דזמרא](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesukei_Dezimra); I haven't seen this anywhere else.

Where does this come from?
Are there any other locations?

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the interesting question! Please consider de-jargonifying your terms so that the question is accessible to non-Hebrew-readers. This is not official policy on this site, but here are my thoughts on jargon, which I wrote up as a guideline for mi.yodeya: http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/01/guidelines-jargon.html

Comment: @Isaac: I was wondering about that.  Can you edit the question to the level of accessibility you feel is best?

Comment: I don't have time to do that right now; maybe later, or maybe someone else can take a stab. In the mean time, those who are interested in discussing/defining this issue should go here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52/should-we-have-a-jargon-policy-guideline

Comment: @Isaac: I'm not sure how necessary it is here at all, except possibly for `תפילין` (linked).  The parts of Davening are not, IMHO, worth translating; it wouldn't do much good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Sepharadim don't touch the tefillin at "oter yisrael b'tifarah", because morning berachot are said at home, before one puts on tefillin.
- At "yotzer or, u'voreh choshech", you touch the shel-yad only, and kiss your hand. (Ben Ish Hai Shemot 1, Kaf HaHayyim 59:2)
- At "kadosh kadosh kadosh" in the beracha of yotzer or,  some have the minhag to touch the shel-yad only, and kiss your hand. (Ben Ish Hai Shemot 2, Kaf HaHayyim 59:25)
- At the 2 mentions of the tefillin shel yad in k'riat sh'ma, you touch the shel yad, then kiss your hand. At the 2 mentions of the tefillin shel rosh in k'riat sh'ma, you touch the shel rosh, then kiss your hand. (Shulchan Aruch 61:25, Ben Ish Hai Vayera 12, Kaf HaHayyim 61:66) (Since these are places where you mention the shel yad, followed by the shel rosh, back to back, it works out that you touch the shel yad, kiss your hand, touch the shel rosh, and kiss your hand, in that order.)
- At "ga'al yisrael", you touch the shel rosh only, and **don't** kiss your hand. (Ben Ish Hai Beshallah 1)

Comment: I assume that פותח את ידך is the same as וקשרתם...?

Comment: @SLaks: I don't see instructions to do it at פותח את ידך in any of my siddurim. Rather, the sephardic custom is to open our hands, palms up, like we're receiving Hashem's bounty from heaven. (Ben Ish Hai Vayiggash 12)

Comment: @SLaks: I got that wrong about פותח את ידך. We don't have the paseukim that you mention to say פותח את ידך right after donning the tefillin. It's פותח את ידך during Ashrei where the sephardic custom is to open our hands.

Answer (score 3):

The Ben Ish Chai writes (Purim, 9) that when reading the megilla on Purim morning, one should kiss his tefillin at "ויקר" in the verse "ליהודים היתה אורה ושמחה וששון ויקר".

Answer (score 3):

No written source that I know of, but I've been told by Rabbis in the know, that the Lubavitcher Rebbe would kiss his tefilin in uva l'tzion by "v'nizkeh (shel yad), v'nichye (shel rosh), v'nireh (eyes, then lips)". Shouldn't be too hard to trace, though. Plenty of videos of the Rebbe davening.

Comment: Many Lubavichers also do so at פותח את ידך in אשרי.

Comment: @yoel, True. It's listed in the question itself, so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Not listed in the question are when saying "פותח את ידך...‏" after donning *t'filin* before wrapping them around the fingers and when mentioning *t'filin* in the two paragraphs from *Bo* said while wearing *t'filin*. (OTOH, those are arguably not the "in davening" sought.)

Comment: I'm told that the Ben Ish Chai says that while reading the megilla Purim morning, one should kiss his tefillin at "ויקר" in ליהודים היתה אורה ושמחה וששון ויקר.

Comment: @jake, good answer! Why don't you add it as an answer rather than a comment? (OTOH, I don't see it in the _Ben Ish Chay_, first year, _Vayera_, _Chaye Sara_, or _T'tzave_.)

Comment: I thought the main thrust of the question was "where does this come from?" as in the sources for the customs that @SLaks mentioned, which I don't know. I'm sure there are many places in the davening where people have a custom to kiss their tefillin.

Comment: @jake: I'm asking both; feel free to add that as an answer (preferably with a source)

Answer (score 1):

[Menachos 36b](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l5203.htm) says that one should constantly be touching his Tefilin, in order not to forget that he is wearing it.

> אמר רבה בר רב הונא חייב אדם למשמש בתפילין בכל שעה קל וחומר מציץ ומה
>   ציץ שאין בו אלא אזכרה אחת אמרה תורה והיה על מצחו תמיד שלא תסיח דעתו
>   ממנו תפילין שיש בהן אזכרות הרבה על אחת כמה וכמה

This is codified in [Orach Chaim 28:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=77&hilite=).

Comment: So why are there specific times and why are they all during davening?

Comment: @DoubleAA: The specific times has been answered already, however no answer gave the source. It is done during Davening as that is when we generally wear Tefilin.

Comment: No, _what_ the specific times are has been answered already. _Why_ are there specific times at all, according to your answer? You have not provided a source for _why_ there are specific times at all