# Do we have to kiss our tefilin?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tefilin

In most Seddurim, at certain points during davening (Ashrei, Shema, etc.), it says to touch and kiss the tefilin.
The Shulchan Aruch [(28:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.28.1?lang=bi) says

> חייב אדם למשמש בתפילין בכל שעה שלא יסיח דעתו מהם
>   A person should regularly touch his tefillin so that he should not become distracted from them

Is there any source for kissing the tefilin, or is it just "well-known" as [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7331/where-in-davening-do-we-kiss-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F) question says? (The Shulchan Aruch above doesn't say anything about kissing them.)
(This is not a question of whether or not it is preferable to kiss them in general, because the Shulchan Aruch finishes off the Siman saying scholars kiss their tefilin when putting them on and taking them off, rather, it is a question specifically at the times mentioned in the siddur, as mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7331/where-in-davening-do-we-kiss-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F))

---

If there is a solid proof to kissing the tefilin, nowadays, when most shuls require a mask in order to attend, is it preferable to try to kiss the tefilin, e.g. stepping away to lower your mask? Would it count to touch the tefilin and put your hand to your mask? Or does it make more sense to only touch the tefilin.

Comment: Joseph Caro did not want Jews to kiss tephillin. It is a Muslim practice, not Jewish.

Comment: Even if it's preferable to kiss your tefillin it's not preferable to take your mask off.

Comment: @TurkHill Joseph Caro wrote: מנהג החכמים לנשק התפילין בשעת הנחתן ובשעת חליצתן

Comment: @TurkHill It is a Muslim practice to kiss your tefillin??

Comment: What? I didn't know Muslims put on tephillin

Comment: @KapinKrunch I didn't say they put on tephillin. I said that the practice of kissing "holy" objects was a Muslim practice.

Comment: @Dani can you split off your second question and post it as something like "How do you kiss tzitzit or tefillin while wearing a mask?" And ask whether one should kiss with the mask on (no physical contact) or lower the mask, or not kiss? I was wondering that this morning.

Comment: @rosends You can if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chayai Adam 14:15 says the Minhag is to kiss the Tefilin at the time of Mismush because of Chivuv Mitzva.

[והמנהג לנשק בשעת משמוש... משום חיבוב מצווה](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49395&st=&pgnum=39)

Comment: Any thoughts about the second part of my question?

Comment: @Dani - My only thoughts on your second part are you do the best you can under extenuating circumstances.