# How to kiss tzitzit while wearing a mask

Tags: tefilla, minhag, tzitzis, kissing

An offshoot of [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114573/do-we-have-to-kiss-our-tefilin?noredirect=1#comment383667_114573) question.

It is some people's practice to [kiss](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=kiss%20tzitzis) their tzitzit during davening. When one wears a mask, one is really kissing the interior of the mask. Should one still bring the tzitzit to his lips or is there no value if he does not pull down the mask?

BTW, I spoke to my LOR who said he doesn't know the answer and so he holds his tzitzit and gives a squeeze in his hand to remind himself, so that the holding performs the same function as kissing, but he has no idea if this is right.

Comment: Until the mask comes off, I'm following the opinion of the Vilna Gaon to not kiss the tzitzit but to look at them. See related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/kissing-tzitzis-during-shema

Comment: Same question, mezuzah

Comment: There were gedolim who never kissed mezuza rather looked at it,see Leket Yosher about the minhag of the Terumas Hadeshen. It is the gesture which shows chivuv ,so even if one doesnt actually kiss it ,the gesture is the main thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rav Moshe Heinemann [says](https://images.shulcloud.com/993/uploads/Corona-Backyard-Minyanim.pdf)

> One should kiss his ציצית and תפילין through his mask at the places
> where he is נוהג to kiss them.